# Java and Windows Regional Settings

Tags: java, date-format, dst

Sorry if this is a re-post. I did not find a suitable answer.

Please ignore best practices and use of deprecated apis.

I want to format the following date "**Mon May 19 02:16:52 EDT 2003**" into "**MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss**". Again, I only want to change the output format and this is being executed from my laptop which is in EST.

My Windows Regional Settings are:

*Current time zone: **Eastern Daylight Time***

*Timezone: **(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)***

*Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving changes: **Checked***

This java code does it:

```
Date aDate = new Date("Mon May 19 02:16:52 EDT 2003");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + sdf.format(aDate));
```

Output is

```
Formatted Date: 05/19/2003 02:16:52
```

Now I change the windows setting to the following (only uncheck the DST setting)

*Current time zone: **Eastern Daylight Time***

*Timezone: **(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)***

*Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving changes: **Checked***

Output is:

```
Formatted Date: 05/19/2003 01:16:52
```

Questions:

1. Why is the output off by an hour?
2. Does java use Windows DST settings even when formatting? I though java maintains its own data for DST settings times for various timezones.

Comment: Yes, Java uses OS settings be it Windows or another OS

Comment: Why would java change my output though? I am telling java what date to use and what format to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, dates are stored by a long value that represents the number of milliseconds past some epoch. When you clicked off the daylight savings time on you machine, you changed your timezone. So Java is using the same time number with a different timezone and that's why you have what you have

Comment: Please check the correct answer when you are satisfied (there might be a wait time on this)

Answer (score 1):

Because the summer time is one hour ahead of the normal one. Set your calendar to January and you'll see no difference.

Comment: Interesting. So when does Java use the Olson Timezone DB if it ends up using the OS settings anyways

Answer (score 1):

When you create the Date Java will internally store the value as GMT. When you format the date to a String Java will use your computers time zone to convert the date to your local time zone, which is the reason that you get different results. As an example, if I run the following code on my computer (with time zone CEST):

```
System.out.println(new Date("Mon May 19 02:16:52 UTC 2003"));
System.out.println(new Date("Mon May 19 02:16:52 EDT 2003"));
System.out.println(new Date("Mon May 19 02:16:52 PST 2003"));
```

I get the following results:

```
Mon May 19 04:16:52 CEST 2003
Mon May 19 08:16:52 CEST 2003
Mon May 19 12:16:52 CEST 2003
```

If you want more predictable results you could either not supply a time zone in your input (e.g. as long as input and output is performed in the same time zone it stays the same) or use a more reliable method where you specify which time zone to use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because by default SimpleDateFormat prints date in your system time zone. To check it, add time zone output to format: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z" So you'll see in what time zone it actually prints the value.

If you want to control, in what timezone you want to format value, use  DateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone z) method.